# Why I cannot set div background using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm new on web programming and jQuery.

Purpose:
I tried to set div background in red by using the following code, however it failed.

`$(stepBox).find(".image").css('background-color', 'red');`

May I know what's the problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>  

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var stepBox = "<div class='step' id='1'>"
                        + "    <div class='summary'>summary</div>"
                        + "    <div class='image'>image</div>"
                        + "</div>";

            $(".steps").append(stepBox);

            $(stepBox).find(".image").css('background-color', 'red');
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="steps">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Resolved:

change it as (add $ sign)

```
var stepBox = $("<div class='step' id='1'>"
             + "    <div class='summary'>summary</div>"
             + "    <div class='image'>image</div>"
             + "</div>");
```

Thanks guys.

```
@Abovestand  upvote (I get the point and convert string to object)       
@JanR  mark as answer  (first response)      
@Pratik Thakkar  upvote (alternative method)
```

Further information, as "steps" likely has many "step", so I prefer operate "image" which belongs to "step" in "stepBox".

`$('.step .image').css('background-color', 'red');` should be workable as well. (@Pratik Thakkar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies within this line:

```
$(stepBox).find(".image").css('background-color', 'red');
```

As per the `.find()` documentation: *Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.* Which basically means search the current object for any child objects that match the search. However `stepBox` is not a jquery object or element.

You want to change it to:

```
$(".steps").find(".image").css('background-color', 'red');
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/t7b84bsg/

Comment: Thanks, shall I convert 'stepBox' to jQuery element or object? Thinking about design issue, 'image' is belong to 'step' not 'steps', therefore I avoid to use '$(".steps").find(".image")...' directly.

Comment: add a class to the image when you add it, that way you can reference it directly.

Answer (score 1):

The variable "stepBox" is a string. jQuery needs a reference to an element. This will work:

```
 $(".steps").find(".image").css('background-color', 'red');
```

EDIT:

In response to your comment, yes. To create a jQuery element from a string you can do this:

```
var stepBoxEle = $.parseHTML(stepbox)[0];
```

Unfortunately appending stepBoxEle to the page only copies it, so editing it afterwards won't change things on the page. You can edit stepBoxEle before appending though like:

```
$(stepBoxEle).find(".image").css('background-color', 'red');
$(".steps").append(stepBoxEle);
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below should work perfectly. All you need to do is select the .image class in the div with class .step

```
$('.step .image').css('background-color', 'red');
```

You can alternately use the below code, if you want all elements with the class ".image" within the div with class .steps

```
$('.steps .image').css('background-color', 'red');
```

See Fiddle link below
http://jsfiddle.net/yxzrut2q/